# Fantasy book follow the chief's son as he makes a rite of passage and gains berserker powers

Tags: story-identification, books, ebooks

Looking for a book where the plot is basically the main character is the chief's son, he has a romance interest and a antagonist who’s a boy his age likes to bully him.

Fast forward some time and he goes on a rite of passage type journey in his ancestral homelands and gains a berserker type power. He comes home to find his love interest is pronounced "dead" but really she left because she thought he was dead, so he leaves home and joins a mercenary band.

I forgot the rest but by the end of the book series, the main character ends up dying after killing his mortal enemy.

I read this on Kindle, in maybe 2019 - I can’t remember exactly. And I remember in the third book of the series he found the love interest but she ultimately got killed by the antagonist after he stormed a castle.

The protagonist killed a bunch of people and earned a nickname for it. When he berserks, he kind of just gets bloodlust and loses control of who’s friend or foe and kills indiscriminately.

The protagonist also seems to been European or his people are based off of European culture.

Comment: I made a few tweaks to your question. When did you read this? Was this as a Kindle? Did you buy it? Was it free? Do you remember other books you read at the time? Did the protagonist seem European? Asian? African? When berserking, does he lose consciousness? Become a slavering beast? Does he eventually find the love interest again?

Comment: So it was on kindle, I read this in maybe 2019? I can’t remember exactly. 
And I remember in like the third book of the series he found the love interest but she ultimately got killed my the antagonist after he stormed a castle and (my memory is a little fuzzy) but he killed a bunch of people and earned a nickname for it, when he beserks, he kind of just gets blood lust and loses control of who’s friend or foe and kills indiscriminately, I hope this helps!

Comment: This sounds a lot like the Druss series of novels; https://davidgemmell.fandom.com/wiki/Druss_the_Legend_series

Comment: Except Druss was married to his wife and she was kidnapped by slavers whilst he was chopping wood,

Comment: I might need to check out druss! I’m getting back into reading more often I just really lived the book I’m talking about I just haven’t been able to find it lol